# 404 Not found in angular with codeigniter

Tags: angularjs, codeigniter

My directory structure is like:

```
project


            ->application
            ->system
            ->client
                --->app
                    --->restock

->index.php
```

Now, I can access my CI application just fine from the root.

```
     localhost/project/index.php
```

But on trying to access

```
    localhost/project/restock
```

I get a 404 not found.

I am using `stateprovider` for routing:

```
$stateProvider
      .state('restock', {
        url: '/restock',
        templateUrl: 'app/restock/restock.html',
        controller: 'restockCtrl'
      });
  });
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Show your `.htaccess` file.

Comment: @Tpojka: I copied one that is generated by yo angular-fullstack generator.

Comment: @Tpojka here: https://github.com/angular-fullstack/generator-angular-fullstack/blob/master/app/templates/client/.htaccess